# How to exclude all results except

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing a query that uses 2 types of employee `ID's`, 'E' & 'S'. I need to exclude all the 'S' `ID's` EXCEPT S111111. How do I do this?

```
Select * from Roster where left(id, 1) <> 'S'
```

Comment: `OR id = 'S111111'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from Roster where left(id,1) = 'E' or id='S111111'
```

Comment: Thanks, I did where id LIKE 'E%' or id LIKE 'S111111'

Answer (score 0):

Select * from Roster where left(id,1) <> 'S'
union
Select * from Roster where id='S111111'

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from roster where columnname like 'E%' or id=S111111
```